# How to add bitlocker encrypted Windows 10 to grub bootloader?

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, grub2, encryption, bootloader

Ubuntu 18.04 is installed on /dev/sdb2, grub bootloader on /dev/sdb1 and Windows 10 on a separate SSD /dev/sdc1. I tried `update-grub` and `os-prober` but grub would not find it. How can I add bitlocker encrypted Windows 10 entry to grub bootloader?

Comment: Did you ever find this one out? I'm stuck as well and my next attempt will be to unecnrypt, add to grub, re-encrypt, hope that works & survives next grup-updates...

Comment: I can't remember sorry. Maybe you can install grub-customizer with `sudo apt install grub-customizer` and try to add the boot entry manually. It is a neat UI with templates, I think also for Windows entries. Then restarting a view times into both operating systems. Maybe this works.